# C - child process of a child process

Tags: c, process, fork

I have to reproduce a process family like this: father --> child --> grandson.
I don't understand why the grandson code is never executed.
My code scheme is like this:

```
int main() {

    int fatherProcess, p1, p2;

    p1 = fork();

    if(p1 <0) {
        perorr("Failed to create P1\n");

    } else if(p1 == 0) {
        //child code
        p2 = fork();


        if(p2 < 0) {
            perorr("Failed to create P2\n");

        } else if(p2 == 0) {
            //grandson code
            pritnf("Hello I'm the GRANDSON\n");

        } else {
            //child code
            pritnf("Hello I'm the CHILD\n");
        }

    } else {
        //father code

        pritnf("Hello I'm the father\n");

    }

    return 0;
}
```

The stamp that I get is:
 - Hello I'm the GRANDSON
 - Hello I'm the father

Comment: You should use `pid_t` as type for your p1 and p2

Comment: Can you please post the correct code? `pritnf` and `perorr` will not compile. You also missed the includes. When I fix it, I get the expected output: https://ideone.com/VmgvFN

Comment: are the typo's (`pritnf` instead of `printf` and `perorr` instead of `perror`) part of your actual code ?

Comment: This doesn't even compile ('pritnf'). Please give us the code that you are actually using.

Comment: This isn't my real code...because I have to use this schema in a bigger program...so I should want to understand if the structure is correct

Comment: @GiorgioDiRocco, your structure is correct. You just need to correct `pritnf` to `printf`. Correct it and compile and run it you will get the below output Hello I'm the father
Hello I'm the CHILD
Hello I'm the GRANDSON

Comment: @GiorgioDiRocco : then please fix the typo's, and try running the code before posting it. It should work.

Comment: #iclunde <stdnio.h>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made two spelling error. I have fixed it and you can try the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main() {

    int fatherProcess, p1, p2;

    p1 = fork();

    if(p1 <0) {
        perror("Failed to create P1\n");

    } else if(p1 == 0) {
        //child code
        p2 = fork();


        if(p2 < 0) {
            perror("Failed to create P2\n");

        } else if(p2 == 0) {
            //grandson code
            printf("Hello I'm the GRANDSON\n");

        } else {
            //child code
            printf("Hello I'm the CHILD\n");
        }

    } else {
        //father code

        printf("Hello I'm the father\n");

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Your code:

```
perorr --> perror
pritnf --> printf
```